# Jacoco coverage for switch statement

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, code-coverage, jacoco

I am working to get 100% code coverage for a library I am working on and I seem to have some issues with a switch statement and the coverage which I simply don't understand.

I am currently using Jacoco 0.7.2 because every newer version seems to break with Robolectrics.

I test a simple switch statement:

```
public enum Type {
    NONE, LEGACY, AKS
}

private static Class<?> getCipherClass(Type type) {
    switch (type) {
        case LEGACY:
            return CipherWrapperLegacy.class;
        case AKS:
            return CipherWrapperAks.class;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

The test I wrote contains the following checks (I have to use reflection as the method is private):

```
final CipherWrapper instance = CipherWrapper.createInstance(mockContext, CipherWrapper.Type.LEGACY, ALIAS);
assertNotNull(instance);

Method getCipherMethod = TestUtils.makeMethodAccessible(CipherWrapper.class, "getCipherClass", CipherWrapper.Type.class);
assertNull(getCipherMethod.invoke(instance, CipherWrapper.Type.NONE));
assertEquals(CipherWrapperAks.class, getCipherMethod.invoke(instance, CipherWrapper.Type.AKS));
assertEquals(CipherWrapperLegacy.class, getCipherMethod.invoke(instance, CipherWrapper.Type.LEGACY));
```

The result is not what I have expected:

[image: Jacoco code coverage result]

The image is a bit confusing as the yellow line suggests that there is something missing. The green icon tells me that 3 of 3 branches are covered.

I also tested to extend the switch case with `case NONE` and a fall through but it didn't change anything.

The only thing I can do is to replace the switch with if/else and then I get 100% coverage.

Currently I have 98% coverage but I nothing is missed based on the overview:
[image: Jacoco overall coverage]

Comment: You're not testing the case when you pass in `null`, for one thing...

Comment: There is one test case missing, which is passing in a null value for `type`, which should result in a `NullPointerException`. (Honestly, I stop to stretch before hitting enter, and jonskeet swoops in with the same point...)

Comment: Hm... true, but why is it not mentioned as a branch somewhere? The overview shows I do not miss any complexity, which is normally the case if I miss a null path... anyway will test it and come back with results

Comment: Any clue how I can pass a null value into the `invoke()` method? Every way I tried I get an InvokationException. Obviously it does not understand that the null I pass is of the enum type, which kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the invoke method doesn't like you putting in an anonymous variable:

```
getCipherMethod.invoke(instance, (CipherWrapper.Type) null);
```

Then try it with a named variable:

```
CipherWrapper.Type nullType = null;
getCipherMethod.invoke(instance, nullType);
```

Also, you should check if the invocation exception is just wrapping an exception caused by invoking the method rather than an error with invocation itself.

Comment: Indeed, seems that `invoke()` creates a new exception and has the original, in my case expected, NullPointerException as "cause". My catch block looks like this: `catch (InvocationTargetException e) { if (e.getCause() instanceof NullPointerException) { .... } }`