# Why is JaCoCo not covering my String switch statements?

Tags: java, junit, switch-statement, jacoco, codecov

I have a `switch` statement that extracts an addressing mode from a `String` and I've written unit tests to cover, what I thought was every eventuality but JaCoCo seems to skip my `switch` statements, resulting in lower coverage.

Why, if all my `case` statements, including a default are being executed in tests, would the `switch` statement not be counted as hit?

[image]

Comment: This issue might be relevant: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/116. And its 4-year old parent too (https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15)

Comment: Another option is that you don't test for NPE if `t[OP_ADD]` is null. Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288022/jacoco-coverage-for-switch-statement?rq=1

Comment: I'm not testing for `NullPointerException` though, I'm testing for `ArrayOutOfBoundsIndexException` as some instructions have an addressing mode, e.g. `OP_LDA_I` while some are immediately addressed e.g. `OP_SEC`

Comment: Technically, `t[OP_ADD]` can be null, in this case, NullPointerException will occur. To cover this case you'll need to add tests for null values, as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh, you are saying I should test for null.   But that would show up in the `if`, so why would that affect my `switch` coverage?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the switch by String

```
class Fun  {
  static int fun(String s) {
    switch (s) {
      case "I":
        return 1;
      case "A":
        return 2;
      case "Z":
        return 3;
      case "ABS":
        return 4;
      case "IND":
        return 5;
      default:
        return 6;
    }
  }
}
```

Oracle Java compiler generates bytecode similar to the following code (Eclipse Compiler for Java generates slightly different bytecode)

```
    int c = -1;
    switch (s.hashCode()) {
      case 65: // +1 branch
        if (s.equals("I")) // +2 branches
          c = 0;
        break;
      case 73: // +1 branch
        if (s.equals("A")) // +2 branches
          c = 1;
        break;
      case 90: // +1 branch
        if (s.equals("Z")) // +2 branches
          c = 2;
        break;
      case 64594: // +1 branch
        if (s.equals("ABS")) // +2 branches
          c = 3;
        break;
      case 72639: // +1 branch
        if (s.equals("IND")) // +2 branches
          c = 4;
        break;
      default: // +1 branch
    }
    switch (c) {
      case 0: // +1 branch
        return 1;
      case 1: // +1 branch
        return 2;
      case 2: // +1 branch
        return 3;
      case 3: // +1 branch
        return 4;
      case 4: // +1 branch
        return 5;
      default: // +1 branch
        return 6;
    }
```

So that original switch-statement with 6 cases is represented in bytecode by a switch with 6 cases for `hashCode` of `String` plus 5 if-statements plus another switch with 6 cases. To see this bytecode you can use `javap -c`.

JaCoCo performs analysis of bytecode and in versions lower than 0.8.0 has no filter for switch by string. Your tests cover cases, where conditions in if-statements evaluate to `true`, but not the cases where they evaluate to `false`. Personally I would advise to simply ignore missing cases, because the goal is not to test that compiler generates proper code, but to test that your application behaves correctly. But for a sake of completeness of this answer - here is tests that cover all bytecode branches:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FunTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    // original strings:
    assertEquals(1, Fun.fun("I"));
    assertEquals(2, Fun.fun("A"));
    assertEquals(3, Fun.fun("Z"));
    assertEquals(4, Fun.fun("ABS"));
    assertEquals(5, Fun.fun("IND"));

    // same hash codes, but different strings:
    assertEquals(6, Fun.fun("\0I"));
    assertEquals(6, Fun.fun("\0A"));
    assertEquals(6, Fun.fun("\0Z"));
    assertEquals(6, Fun.fun("\0ABS"));
    assertEquals(6, Fun.fun("\0IND"));

    // distinct hash code to cover default cases of switches
    assertEquals(6, Fun.fun(""));
  }
}
```

And report generated by JaCoCo 0.7.9 as a proof:

[image: coverage report]

[**JaCoCo version 0.8.0** provides filters](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html), including filter for bytecode that `javac` produces for switch by string. And so generates following report even without additional tests:

[image: coverage report]

Comment: So, it's find `Strings` that have the same hascode as all my case statement `String`s or grin and bare it?  :(
Thanks

Comment: @RossDrew personally I would advise to simply ignore missing cases

Comment: I accepted this answer until I wrote test cases to cover it.  I added tests that check each of my `switch` cases against cases where the `hashcode()` is the same but `equals()` is different.  Which should, check the nested `if` but the code coverage remains the same.

https://github.com/rossdrew/emuRox/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/rox/emu/p6502/op/OpCodeConverterSpec.groovy

Comment: @RossDrew "accepted this answer" - maybe you upvoted, but definitely not accepted. "but the code coverage remains the same" - I guess that you don't test "default" case of switch statements. Answer was updated to be more precise and include tests. But once again - IMO this is overkill.

Comment: I accepted it then took it back again.  It is overkill but I like my 100% badge and if it leads to learning more about my language and tools, it's all a good thing :)
As for the default test case not being tested.  The code coverage says 16 hits in there.

Comment: @RossDrew addition of debug output `if (t[OP_ADD].startsWith("\0")) System.out.println("TESTED");` just before the switch tells me that you don't actually test cases of the same hash code. You can also confirm this with help of debugger. In your tests `\0` should be placed before `I`, `A`, `Z`, `ABS` and `IND` as in my answer, not before `OP`, i.e. `OP_ORA_\0ABS` and etc.

Comment: @Godin, would you know why such code is generated ? Is that an optimization trick? What would be the reason?

Comment: @BaptistePernet see JSR-334 (https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr334/index.html) "In order to keep strings in switch a small language change, the JVM lookupswitch and tableswitch instructions in Java SE 7 do not support switching on a string. Instead, Java compilers are responsible for translating a switch on strings into some sequence of byte code instructions with the proper semantics. Many valid and efficient translation schemes are possible that have better expected performance than successive comparisons of the string being switched on with each case label constant."

Comment: I got around this by making a map from String to return value.

Comment: This drove me crazy for hours. I had a similar issue with at `when` statement.
I was very confused as to why I wasn't getting full coverage, i thought I had written my tests wrong. Updating from 0.8.3 to 0.8.6 fixed it. Thank you @Godin